# how to create an explain plan for the below query? I'm getting ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement error

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, explain

I'm getting ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement error when i tried. but the sql query is running fine without explain.

Query: `create or replace view TaskView as
   select T1.PersonID,T2.ID ,T2.Task from Table1 T1,Table2 T2
   where T1.TaskID=T2.ID;`

[image: error]

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really stop using those ancient and outdated implicit joins in the WHERE clause and start using the "modern" (introduced 20 years ago) explicit JOIN operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CREATE VIEW statement has no execution plan as the SELECT will not be evaluated when you create the view. You need to first create the view, then run EXPLAIN on a query using the view:

```
create or replace view TaskView 
as
select T1.PersonID,T2.ID ,T2.Task 
from Table1 T1,Table2 T2
where T1.TaskID=T2.ID;
```

Then

```
explain plan 
  set statement_id = 'TASK'
select *
from taskview;
```

or simply explain the underlying query:

```
explain plan 
  set statement_id = 'TASK'
select T1.PersonID,T2.ID ,T2.Task 
from Table1 T1,Table2 T2
where T1.TaskID=T2.ID;
```

Comment: thanks for your guiding. it worked without any error.
can't we try the way i tried? is this the only way for this?